# A step in verifying a stopping time.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Suppose $X$ is a cadlag process adapted to $\{\mathcal F_t\}$ and $H$ is a closed set.Verify $\sigma_H\triangleq\inf\{t\ge0:X_t(\omega)\in H\}$ is a stopping time .

The first step is:

$$\{\sigma_H\le t\}=\{X_0\in H\}\cup\{X_s\in H\text{ or }X_{s-}\in H \text{ for some }s\in\color{red}{(}0,t]\}$$

I wonder if I can omit the "$\text{ or }X_{s-}\in H$"?i.e.
$$\{\sigma_H\le t\}=\{X_0\in H\}\cup\{X_s\in H\text{ for some }s\in\color{red}{(}0,t]\}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality

$$\{\sigma_H \leq t\} = \{X_0 \in H\} \cup \{X_s \in H \, \text{or} \, X_{s-} \in H \, \text{for some} \, s \in (0,t]\} \tag{1}$$

does **not** hold. Consider the following counter example:

Consider the (deterministic) cádlág process $$X_t := \begin{cases} t & t<1 \\ 0 & t \geq 1. \end{cases}$$ and set $H:=\{1\}$. Then it follows easily from the definition of $\sigma_H$ that $\sigma_H = \infty$ and therefore

$$\{\sigma_H \leq t\} = \emptyset$$

for all $t \geq 0$. On the other hand, the right-hand side of $(1)$ does not equal $\emptyset$ for $t \geq 1$; this follows from the fact that $X_{1-} = 1 \in H$.